# Getting error while using state in class based component in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web-deployment

[this is the code that i am writing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9RTe.png)

[It is the error that is showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQX21.png)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please attach the code, not images ... They are hard to tell (if its an error it might help)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is that you are directly implementing the map function without enclosing it in any HTML tag.

For more reference: [See this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-state-on-react-class-components)

Do it like this, your issue will be resolved

```js
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.articles.map((element) => {
          return <div>// Your further code here</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly return the map function without enclosing it in any HTML tag.

You just need to remove the curly braces.

```
  render() {
    return this.state.articles.map((element) => {
      return <div>{element}</div>;
    });
  }
```